# Store data in class

Tags: c++

I have a class that picks up data from the serial port and I receive the amount of switches a LDR measures just 1 and 0.

Now I would like to store this in a class as long the program runs how can I accomplish this with managed variables?

Note the serial class runs every second so when I create open a class that I use now
 StoreClass Store

```
Store.Value = LDR_Value; // LDR_Value is the value from the serial bus
```

When I do this there always will be a copy of StoreClass be created and that doesn't do the trick.

Please help me out here.

Comment: Can you give more code about your class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to accumulate your data in a container, use standard containers. I think `std::vector` would suffice as a good container for your job:

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   vector<DataType> dataReceived; //define data container

   DataType buffer; //type of your data
   while(recevingFromDevice) //loop that keeps running as long as you're receiving from your device
   {
      buffer = getDataFromDevice(); //buffer what you receive from the device
      dataReceived.push_back(buffer); //add this buffer to the stack of data
   }
   //now dataReceived is an array with all received data
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want a container to store all the values received. If you have a class named `StoreClass`, you can create a `vector` member and do this:

```
class StoreClass
{
  public:
    void AddValue(int v) { m_values.push_back(v); }

  private:
    std::vector<int> m_values; // Stores all values in order of arrival.
}
```

Now you only need one instance of your class:

```
int main()
{
  StoreClass storage;
  while(StillSerialInput())
  {
    storage.AddValue(GetSerialValue());
  }
}
```